# Why are my Nikon J1 pictures taken with the 30-110 zoom lens black?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-1

Ok, so I'm new to this and we've had this camera for a while. If I use the 10-30 lens, everything is great. Pics and video work fine. If I put on the 30-110 zoom lens, I can barely see anything and the camera won't even take a picture. Flash doesn't work either. I've looked through the PDF camera manual online and still haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I really don't know much about cameras and would be considered a newbie with this.

Comment: Try cleaning the contacts on the lens? Otherwise, lens might be broken.

Comment: What type of lighting conditions are you shooting under? And what mode is the camera in? Can you post an example with EXIF information?

Answer (score 1):

Itai answered this in a comment - clean the contacts on the lens and try again. If it still fails, the lens might be broken. Contact Nikon.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [similar problem with the 10-30 lens](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/service-and-support/service-advisories/i5hz4dok/Technical-Service-Advisory-for-Users-of-the-1-NIKKOR-VR-10-30mm-f%252F3.5-5.6.html) of the same J1 era. It was a manufacturing defect. Nikon fixed it for free.

I suggest you send the lens to Nikon for a repair quote, if cleaning the contacts doesn't resolve the problem.

I got my 10-30 fixed for free this way. You may be out of luck but the repair cost might be small. I also got Nikon to fix a J1 for a very reasonable amount. The internal fuse needed replacing after I had dropped the camera. Obviously some repairs may be uneconomic to repair but Nikon charge only a minimal amount for a quote if you do not authorise the repair.